# Using command line arguments in VBscript

Tags: command-line, vbscript, command-line-arguments

How can I pass and access command line arguments in VBscript?

Answer (score 92):

```
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

For Each arg In args
  Wscript.Echo arg
Next
```

From a command prompt, run the script like this:

```
CSCRIPT MyScript.vbs 1 2 A B "Arg with spaces"
```

Will give results like this:

```
1
2
A
B
Arg with spaces
```

Comment: You can access it directly with `WScript.Arguments.Item(0)`. Item 0 is not the command's name (as it is in other languages); in Aphoria's example above it would be the string "1".

Answer (score 62):

If you need direct access:

```
WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
...
```

Comment: You can also drag and drop a file onto a script in Explorer, which will run the script with the first argument set to the file path and name.

Comment: You might want to use `WScript.Arguments.Count` with this.