# Pass arguments to VBS from Java

Tags: java, parameters, vbscript, runtime, parameter-passing

I am calling a VBS from Java something like this

```
public class CallVBS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:\\openURL.vbs");
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

If my openURL.vbs contains a method like

```
Sub Test(Name,Age,Sex)
```

How do I call the above method present in VBS with the arguments from Java

Answer (score 2):

So just to make a few alterations to AlexR as I think there are a few things that could do with correcting.

Say for example we had a VBS file called MyVBScript.vbs

The content of MyVBScript.vbs would be as folows:

```
name = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
age = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
sex = WScript.Arguments.Item(2)

Call Test(name, age, sex)
```

*Remember that indexes of collections start with 0 as the first occurance*

Now in the Java code to envoke this VBS file we would have the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:\\MyVBScript.vbs " + name + " " + age + " " + sex
```

Kudos to AlexR for the original answer, but I felt it needed a bit of clarifying. I hope this helps people. I'm personally using it in my Java Test harness as a method of launching Quick Test Professional.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is mostly not about java but about VBS. Take a look on this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469754/how-to-pass-and-access-command-line-arguments-in-vbscript) that describes how to read command line arguments in VBS. Generally you have to use built-in object `Wscript.Arguments`. Parse the arguments in your  "main" part of your script and call your subrutine `Test`, e.g.

```
Set name =  Wscript.Arguments(1)
Set age =  Wscript.Arguments(2)
Set sex =  Wscript.Arguments(3)
Call Test(name, age, sex)
```

Now you can call your script from java like following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:\\openURL.vbs " + name + " " + age + " " + sex);
```

Comment: +1 if you let the indices for WScript.Arguments start with 0 and remove the Set (used for assignment of objects only).

Comment: "main" part as in Function Main(). Is that what you are saying ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible `getURL.vbs` could look like this:

```
Option Explicit

WScript.Echo "openURL.vbs"

Dim a0 : a0 = "Def. A. Ult"
If 1 <= WScript.Arguments.Count Then a0 = WScript.Arguments(0)
Dim a1 : a1 = "47.11"
If 2 <= WScript.Arguments.Count Then a1 = WScript.Arguments(1)
Dim a2 : a2 = "neuter"
If 3 <= WScript.Arguments.Count Then a2 = WScript.Arguments(2)

Test a0, a1, a2

Sub Test(name, age, sex)
  WScript.Echo """" & Join(Array(name, age, sex), """, """) & """"
End Sub
```

It looks at the arguments passed via the command line in the top level/'main'/immediately executed/out of Sub/Function part of the VBScript code.

To avoid possible problems with quoting/args containing spaces, I'd use this .exec call:

```
String[] parms = {"wscript", "openURL.vbs", "Anna B. Carlson", "12", "fale"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(parms);
```