# Passing inputs to VBScript from Windows Forms Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vba, email, vbscript

I have created a small desktop application which allows users to log a call with our help desk without the need of a browser or email application (since it is locked down)

Within the form code i call a vbs script which collects system information from WMI and then send an email via outlook/cdo (still deciding on email method)

Below is my form code for the send button.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim strName As String
        Dim strDept As String
        Dim strEmail As String
        Dim strExt As String
        Dim strDesc As String
        Dim strAffect As String

        strName = TextBox1.Text
        strDept = TextBox2.Text
        strEmail = TextBox3.Text
        strExt = TextBox4.Text
        strDesc = RichTextBox1.Text
        strAffect = TextBox5.Text

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\Temp\Support.vbs")
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you!")
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

My problem now comes in with the vbscript code. i need to pass the input parameters from the above form (Name, dept, email address, etc) to the VBScript file to use in the email to support, but i have no idea how to do this.

NOTE: I have very basic vbscript and vb experience and google is my friend, i have searched the internet for 2 days to find a solution but to no avail. So naturally this is my last resource

Below is my VBScript file, (support.vbs) which is called by the above form. Its copy and paste code with modification.

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments

Const NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 19
Const NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 2

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = true
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()

Set objRange = objDoc.Range()
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, NUMBER_OF_ROWS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "System Information For: "
objTable.Cell(2,1).Range.Text = "Manufacturer"
objTable.Cell(3,1).Range.Text = "Model"
objTable.Cell(4,1).Range.Text = "Domain Type"
objTable.Cell(5,1).Range.Text = "Total Physical Memory"
objTable.Cell(6,1).Range.Text = "Processor Manufacturer"
objTable.Cell(7,1).Range.Text = "Processor Name"
objTable.Cell(8,1).Range.Text = "Processor Clock Speed"
objTable.Cell(9,1).Range.Text = "Bios Version"
objTable.Cell(10,1).Range.Text = "Serial Number"
objTable.Cell(11,1).Range.Text = "Video Controller"
objTable.Cell(12,1).Range.Text = "CD-ROM Manufacturer"
objTable.Cell(13,1).Range.Text = "CD-ROM Name"
objTable.Cell(14,1).Range.Text = "KeyBoard"
objTable.Cell(15,1).Range.Text = "Primary Drive Size"
objTable.Cell(16,1).Range.Text = "Primary Drive Space Available"
objTable.Cell(17,1).Range.Text = "Service Pack"
objTable.Cell(18,1).Range.Text = "Windows Version"
objTable.Cell(19,1).Range.Text = "IP Address"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
For Each objItem in colItems
objTable.Rows.Add()
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = UCase(strComputer)
objTable.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = objItem.Manufacturer
objTable.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = objItem.Model
Select Case objItem.DomainRole
Case 0 strComputerRole = "Standalone Workstation"
Case 1 strComputerRole = "Member Workstation"
Case 2 strComputerRole = "Standalone Server"
Case 3 strComputerRole = "Member Server"
Case 4 strComputerRole = "Backup Domain Controller"
Case 5 strComputerRole = "Primary Domain Controller"
End Select
objTable.Cell(4, 2).Range.Text = strComputerRole
objTable.Cell(5, 2).Range.Text = objItem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1048576 & " MB"
Next

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")
For Each objItem in colItems
objTable.Cell(6, 2).Range.Text = objItem.Manufacturer
objTable.Cell(7, 2).Range.Text = objItem.Name
objTable.Cell(8, 2).Range.Text = Round(objItem.MaxClockSpeed) & " MHz"
Next

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
For Each objItem in colItems
objTable.Cell(9, 2).Range.Text = objItem.Version
objTable.Cell(10, 2).Range.Text = objItem.SerialNumber
Next

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_VideoController")
For Each objItem in colItems
objTable.Cell(11, 2).Range.Text = objItem.Name
Next

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_CDROMDrive")
For Each objItem in colItems
objTable.Cell(12, 2).Range.Text = objItem.Manufacturer
objTable.Cell(13, 2).Range.Text = objItem.Name
Next

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Keyboard")
For Each objItem in colItems
objTable.Cell(14, 2).Range.Text = objItem.Caption
Next

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk Where DeviceID = ""C:""")
For Each objItem in colItems
objTable.Cell(15, 2).Range.Text = Round(objItem.Size /1073741824) & " GB"
Next

Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")
For Each objDisk in colDisks
objTable.Cell(16, 2).Range.Text = Round(objDisk.Freespace /1073741824) & " GB"    
Next

Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
objTable.Cell(17, 2).Range.Text = objOperatingSystem.ServicePackMajorVersion & "." & objOperatingSystem.ServicePackMinorVersion
Next

Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
objTable.Cell(18, 2).Range.Text = objOperatingSystem.Caption & "  " & objOperatingSystem.Version
Next


Set IPConfigSet = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select IPAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration ")

For Each IPConfig in IPConfigSet
    If Not IsNull(IPConfig.IPAddress) Then 
        For i=LBound(IPConfig.IPAddress) _
            to UBound(IPConfig.IPAddress)
objTable.Cell(19, 2).Range.Text = IPConfig.IPAddress(i)
        Next
    End If
Next

objTable.AutoFormat(23)

objDoc.SaveAs("C:\Temp\Sysinfo.doc")

objWord.Quit

Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
myAttachments.Add "C:\Temp\Sysinfo.doc"
myItem.Display     '-- Optional --
myItem.To = "email address"
myItem.Subject = ""
myItem.Body = "Dear IT Support" & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "Please assist with the following:" & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "1. Requester info.: " & strName & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "2. Brief summary of the issue and error message," & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "3. Name of system or piece of IT equipment which is not working (eg: screen, keyboard, Internet, etc.)," & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "3.1 Other issues: " & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "3.3 Telephone call issues: Telephone number being dialed/received, time issue occurred, Ext. number where issue occurred," & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "4. Number of users affected by the issue," & vbCRLF & vbCRLF & "5. Step by step replication details(from the login screen until issue occurred)."
```

Comment: Run the VBscript with parameters then use WScript.Arguments(0) from inside the VBS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806713/can-i-pass-an-argument-to-a-vbscript-vbs-file-launched-with-cscript

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f71df6c1-d44e-459d-b211-5cbc1c872e57/vbnet-scriptcontrol-passing-and-returning-parameters?forum=vblanguage), if you have the ability to run the script from within your program using the [ScriptControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227633%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), you can simply add your variables as declaration lines to the script before execution.

If that doesn't appeal to you, according to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469754/using-command-line-arguments-in-vbscript), you can send and retrieve your variables as command line arguments, which you can simply include in your `Process.Start` call.