# I need to call the following:

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

```
Dim oShell

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

oShell.run "cmd /K schtasks /create /tn "procexp" /sc minute /mo 1 /tr  %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\procexp.exe  /ru system "

Set oShell = Nothing
```

---

where the input argument may be "procexp". I have seen countless examples of people doing the same thing using double quotes for a hard coded file location, but nothing using an input argument or variable. What syntax is required so that the command line receives:

```
oShell.run "cmd /K schtasks /create /tn "procexp" /sc minute /mo 1 /tr  %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\procexp.exe  /ru system "
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using command line arguments in VBscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469754/using-command-line-arguments-in-vbscript)

Answer (score -1):

In VBScript, you can use double double-quotes to escape and get a single double-quote e.g. putting "" in a string results in " in the output.

And you can grab an argument using WScript.Arguments ([Using command line arguments in VBscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469754/using-command-line-arguments-in-vbscript)), if you wish to replace procexp.exe with something else.

So, something like...

```
Dim strExe
strExe = WScript.Arguments(0)

oShell.run "cmd /K schtasks /create /tn """ & strExe &  """ /sc minute /mo 1 /tr %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\" & strExe & " /ru system "
```

Comment: I have tried, but this error found in Link photo shows        appearshttps://img2.brain4.photobox.com/597004010ae0b625c22699a2b7a8367d62f0e389199182216c2e8525d666f1b9b43e5b79.jpg